# sql group by find all combinations of two columns distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following table

```
ORDID  EMPID     ITEMCOST       TIME
-------------------------------------    
10023 B2690          675       1992
10024 C3467         8078       1992
10025 B2690        15481       1992
10026 C5621        22884       1992
10027 B2109        30287       1992
10030 B3297        52496       1993
10031 C3467        59899       1993
10032 F5621        67302       1993
10033 G3467        74705       1993
```

and so on many rows.....

I am trying to find out empid who purchased some item in each and every year.
in other words want to find out empid which exist in each and every year in that table.

BTB I am using Oracle 11g Express.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the expected output

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `having` clause where you compare the number of distinct years for each `empid` to the number of distinct years in the data:

```
select empid
from followingtable
group by empid
having count(distinct time) = (select count(distinct time) from followingtable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will also work.

```
SELECT TAB.EMPID FROM
(
     SELECT A.EMPID, COUNT(DISTINCT A.TIME) YEARCOUNT  FROM MY_TABLE A GROUP BY EMPID
) TAB

 WHERE TAB.YEARCOUNT = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.TIME) FROM MY_TABLE B)
```

Comment: Sorry.. its my mistake in changing table name. Its working. Thnx